# Running Tensorflow MobileNet from Java

Tags: tensorflow, java, inception

I am trying to run Tensorflow for image recognition (classification) in Java (JSE not Android).

I am using the code from [here](https://github.com/emara-geek/object-recognition-tensorflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/emaraic/ObjectRecognition/Recognizer.java), and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java).

It works for Inceptionv3 models, and for models retrained from Inceptionv3.

But for MobileNet models, it does not work, (such as following this [article](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/)).

The code works but gives the wrong results (wrong classify labels). What code/settings are required to use MobileNet from Java?

The code that works for Inceptionv3 is

```
try (Tensor image = Tensor.create(imageBytes)) {
    float[] labelProbabilities = executeInceptionGraph(graphDef, image);
    int bestLabelIdx = maxIndex(labelProbabilities);
    result.setText("");
    result.setText(String.format(
        "BEST MATCH: %s (%.2f%% likely)",
        labels.get(bestLabelIdx), labelProbabilities[bestLabelIdx] * 100f));
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "BEST MATCH: %s (%.2f%% likely)",
                labels.get(bestLabelIdx), labelProbabilities[bestLabelIdx] * 100f));
}
```

This works of Inceptionv3 models, but not MobileNet,
Gives the error, "Expects args[0] to be float but the string is provided"

For MobileNet we tried the code,

```
try (Graph g = new Graph()) {
    GraphBuilder b = new GraphBuilder(g);
    // Some constants specific to the pre-trained model at:
    // https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip
    //
    // - The model was trained with images scaled to 224x224 pixels.
    // - The colors, represented as R, G, B in 1-byte each were converted to
    //   float using (value - Mean)/Scale.
    final int H = 224;
    final int W = 224;
    final float mean = 128f;
    final float scale = 1f;
    // Since the graph is being constructed once per execution here, we can use a constant for the
    // input image. If the graph were to be re-used for multiple input images, a placeholder would
    // have been more appropriate.
    final Output<String> input = b.constant("input", imageBytes);
    final Output<Float> output = b.div(
        b.sub(
            b.resizeBilinear(
                b.expandDims(
                    b.cast(b.decodeJpeg(input, 3), Float.class),
                    b.constant("make_batch", 0)),
                    b.constant("size", new int[] {H, W})),
                    b.constant("mean", mean)),
                    b.constant("scale", scale));
                    try (Session s = new Session(g)) {
                        return s.runner().fetch(output.op().name()).run().get(0).expect(Float.class);
                    }
}
```

This works but gives the wrong labels.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? Did you manage to get MobileNet to run without using TensorFlow lite?

Comment: No, we gave up running Tensorflow in Java, and switched to Python.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently also failing at setting up MobileNet. I might switch to Python, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give to use in java :)

I had the same problem, try to change the scale value, I had the same labels from java and python after that.

```
        // - The model was trained with images scaled to 224x224 pixels.
        // - The colors, represented as R, G, B in 1-byte each were converted to
        // float using (value - Mean)/Scale.
        final int H = 224;
        final int W = 224;
        final float mean = 117f;
        final float scale = 255f;
```

Comment: Hi, could you take a look here? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/94071/feature-extraction-with-mobilenet-visualization